# Finding out $S:=1+\frac12-\frac13-\frac14+\frac15+\frac16-\frac17-\frac18+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was willing to determine the sum of following 
$$S:=1+\frac12-\frac13-\frac14+\frac15+\frac16-\frac17-\frac18+\cdots$$

I tried the following 
\begin{align*}
S=&\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\\
 =&\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\int_0^1 x^{2n-2}dx+\int_0^1 x^{2n-1} dx\right)\\
=&\int_0^1 \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(x^{2n-2}+x^{2n-1}\right)\\
=&\int_0^1 [x^{-2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}+x^{-1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}]
\end{align*}
and don't know after his what to do . Can you please help me on this regard?

Thanking you in advance

Comment: you have two geometric series. sum them up and take the limit $x\rightarrow1^-$

Comment: I suppose that the summations start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$S=A+B$$ where $\displaystyle A=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1},\ B=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k}$. Clearly, $B=\displaystyle \frac{\ln 2}{2}$. and, $A=\tan^{-1}1=\pi/4$ which you can find out using your technique as below $$A=\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 x^{2k-2}dx\\=\int_{0}^1\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-2}dx\quad(\mbox{Use Fubini to justify the change of order})\\=\int_{0}^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}1=\pi/4\\
\mbox{similarly, }\ B=\int_{0}^1 \sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}dx\\=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx\\=\frac{\ln 2}{2}$$

Comment: Well you can use DCT here with equal ease but Fubini's theorem also work, with the measures in mind as the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ and the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just write this as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1} + \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac12 \log{2}$$

Comment: But that would be too easy. +1 :-))  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right).$$ Then

$\begin {eqnarray}
S & = & \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2k}\left(\frac{1}{4k-1}+\frac{1}{4k}\right) + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2k+1}\left(\frac{1}{4k+1}+\frac{1}{4k+2}\right) \nonumber \\ & = & \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1} {4k - 1} - \frac {1} {4k + 1}\right) + \sum_{k =1}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1} {4k} - \frac {1} {4k + 2}\right),
\end {eqnarray}$

which is easier to proceed now.

Comment: How is your final result easier??

Comment: Because it's not a strangely alternate series anymore.

Comment: But how is that easier?  How would you propose that one proceed?  Use Digamma function IDs?